# How can I make the body take a style attribute equating to style="background-color: returnBlue()", where returnBlue() returns "blue"?

Tags: javascript, html, css, return, attr

```
<html>
  <body style="background-color: returnBlue()">
    <em>Boy, I sure do wish I existed on something that was blue.</em>
  </body>
</html>
```

The style doesn't make the body blue

```
function returnBlue()
{
   return 'blue';
}
```

How can I make the `returnBlue()` function run and return to an attribute? Thanks!

Comment: `<script>document.body.style.backgroundColor = returnBlue();</script>`

Comment: What is `returnBlue`? CSS can't call JS functions

Comment: You can do something like `<body onload="this.style.backgroundColor = returnBlue()">`, though it isn't the prettiest.

Answer (score 6):

In short, you can't. The style attribute is parsed as CSS and what you're trying to execute is a JavaScript function. There's no way to call JS from CSS.

What you can do, is get a reference to the element in your script and change it manually.

```
var body = document.body;
body.style.backgroundColor = returnBlue();
```

However, rather than trying to style your nodes manually with JavaScript you're probably better defining your styles in CSS classes.

```
/* style.css */
.blue-bg {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Then use the class on your `<body>` tag.

```
<!-- index.html -->
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body class="blue-bg"></body>
```

If you really want to derive your styles programmatically, then you're best off taking a look at a language like [SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/) which supports functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in CSS, you can only do it with JS.

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = returnBlue();
```

Also, why use `returnBlue();` when you are trying to set it to blue? If you want to change the background color using JS just do

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
```

UPDATE:
If you wanted to, you could use JQuery's .css() method and do `$("body").css("background-color: blue;")`

Comment: best speculation is that this isn't actually the full blown code, and there's something within the function that might return colors other than blue, depending on some variable, else it'd make more sense to just set it inline...

Comment: But you could also just have the function change the background color, and then call `returnBlue();` rather than `document.body.style.backgroundColor = returnBlue();`